# Primefaces prime-ui autocomplete forceSelection not working

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I'm using the prime-ui autocomplete control (because the primefaces autocomplete control does not support partial update).  I have my control defined thus:

```
$(document).on('click','.amd_auto_look_up',
function(event){
$('.amd_auto_look_up').puiautocomplete({
  effect: 'fade',
  effectSpeed: 'fast',
  forceSelection: true,
  delay: 100,
  select: function (event, item) {
  updateFunder(item, "amd", $(this))
},
completeSource:function(request, response) {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'http://www.myURI',
 data: {query: request.query},
dataType: "jsonp",
context: this,
success: function(data) {
response.call(this, data);
}
});
}
});                     
event.stopPropagation();
}
);
```

If I set
    forceSelection: false,

all works fine.  If I set

```
forceSelection: true,
```

the autocomplete popup fails to display altogether.  Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of a solution/workaround for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.  Also posted in Prime ui forum. It was a bug. Now fixed. view response here: [forceSelection fix](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=32516&p=103903)